# Difference between Atlassian bitbucket and bamboo

Tags: git, version-control, bitbucket, bamboo

What is the difference between Atlassian bitbucket and bamboo applications? 
I can see that bamboo is a CI/CD tool and bitbucket is a version control, but you can use bitbucket as CI/CD tool i suppose.Why do we need bamboo?

Comment: AFAIK Bitbucket doesn’t have CI tools built in. Instead that is provided by bamboo.

Comment: no .. bitbucket does have CI built in. Does Bamboo provide a repository?

Comment: “Bamboo Cloud is EOL and will be replace by Pipelines.” Is what my search results have come up with. Meaning they’re similar in features, but one will soon go away.

Comment: Apologies btw. I had assumed that “Bitbucket Pipelines” _was_ bamboo.

Comment: Bamboo *Cloud* (hosted by Atlassian) is EOL. Bamboo *Server* (hosted by, um, you) is still a thing.

Answer (score 16):

The confusion here is that Bitbucket server (the on-prem Bitbucket) does not have CI/CD capability, where as Bitbucket cloud does (Bitbucket pipelines).

If you're building an on-prem only CI/CD platform, you need Bamboo (or Jenkins or ...).  If you're building a cloud CI/CD platform, you can do so with just Bitbucket cloud (or with Travis, CircleCI, ...)